# Javadoc comments in module-info

Tags: java, javadoc, java-module, module-info

The Java 9 modules feature adds (higher-level) `module-info` files in addition to the `package-info` files that existed previously. Can `module-info.java` (source-code) files include marked-up comments that the JavaDoc tool will extract and present (usefully) as module-level documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. And the tags supported at module declaration are:

***Module Declaration***

```
{@author}, {@deprecated}, {@provides}, {@see}, {@since}, {@serialField}, {@uses}, {@version}
{@code}, {@docRoot}, {@index}, {@link}, {@linkplain}, {@literal}, {@summary}
```

*Source*:- [Documentation Comment Specification for the Standard doclet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/doc-comment-spec.html)

Amongst these, the newly introduced tags you might further be interested in are :

1. [`@index`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/doc-comment-spec.html#index)
2. [`@summary`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/doc-comment-spec.html#summary)

and then `module` specific

3. [`@provides`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/doc-comment-spec.html#provides)
4. [`@uses`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/doc-comment-spec.html#uses)

Answer (score 7):

In a word - yes. You can see, for example, how Java 9's Javadoc has module-level documentation (including tags for `provides`, `uses`, `moduleGraph`), which then lists the packages in them with their documentation. The packages, in turn, contain classes with their documentation.

As a quick example, check out the [`jdk.jshell` module documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk.jshell-summary.html).

Comment: What about adding comments ( `//` ) over a package export declaration inside `module-info.java`? Is this allowed?

Comment: Yes you can, @MarinosAn

Comment: BTW, `@moduleGraph` isn't supported by the standard doclet; the JDK bubba's are doing something special to support that.